# Can I transfer games from a PS4 to my PS3?

Tags: ps3, ps4

I want to transfer COD: Black Ops II from my brothers PS4 to my PS3, it isn't a game that has been purchased in the PS Store but has been played via game disk.

Is this possible? I don't want to go out and buy a game when I can get it for free...

I know HOW to do it but I want to know whether I can do it between two different gens of console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

The game is programmed to be interpreted by a PS4. The PS3 can't interpret a game made for the PS4. Sony did however have the option to allow backward compatibility, i.e PS3 games that can run on PS4. They did however decide to not go for this.